# Does 'dispatch' have to be called 'dispatch' or can you just call a dispatch without labeling it?

Tags: reactjs, redux, dispatch

I have been calling dispatch on redux for a while but I never used the term 'dispatch'. I just called a function like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

class RecipeList extends React.Component{
    componentDidMount(){
        console.log(this.props)
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <form>
                    <input />
                    <button>SEARCH</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state)=>{
    return {recipe_list: state}
}
const testing = ()=>{
    return {
        type:'TEST'
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {testing: testing})(RecipeList);
```

Is that acceptable? It works.

Comment: I don't see why not :D

Comment: Yes, you are allowed to. The object shorthand for `mapDispatchToProps` has been available for quite a while now.

Answer (score 1):

The [mapDispatchToProps](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#mapdispatchtoprops-object--dispatch-ownprops--object) argument can be [undefined](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#mapdispatchtoprops-object--dispatch-ownprops--object), an [object](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#object-shorthand-form) or a [function](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#dispatch). If it's undefined then react-redux will add `dispatch` to props.

Below are 3 examples how you can use it with undefined, a function or an object and an example with the react-redux [hooks](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks). I would advice using hooks as that is the direction React is going (instead of HOC like connect).

```js
const {
  Provider,
  connect,
  useSelector,
  useDispatch,
} = ReactRedux;
const { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } = Redux;

const initialState = {
  items: [{ id: 1, name: 'item 1' }],
};
//action types
const DELETE = 'DELETE';
//action creators
const deleteItem = (id) => ({
  type: DELETE,
  payload: id,
});
const reducer = (state, { type, payload }) => {
  console.log('action:', type, 'payload:', payload);
  return state;
};
//creating store with redux dev tools
const composeEnhancers =
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  composeEnhancers(
    applyMiddleware(() => (next) => (action) =>
      next(action)
    )
  )
);
//you should use reselect here but for simplicity I didn't
const mapStateToProps = (state, { id }) => ({
  item: state.items.find((item) => item.id === id),
});
//if mapDispatchToProps is undefined then react-redux
//  will add dispatch to props, here is how you can delete
const ItemMapDispatchUndefined = ({ item, dispatch }) => (
  <button onClick={() => dispatch(deleteItem(item.id))}>
    undefined - delete {item.name}
  </button>
);
const ConnectedDispatchUndefined = connect(mapStateToProps)(
  ItemMapDispatchUndefined
);
//if mapDispatchToProps is an object then react-redux
//  will take the properties of that object and if a
//  property is a functoin it will wrap that function
//  in a new function that will automatically dispatch
//  the return value when that function is called
const ItemMapDispatchObject = ({ item, deleteItem }) => (
  // no dispatch needed but still need to pass id to deleteItem
  <button onClick={() => deleteItem(item.id)}>
    object - delete {item.name}
  </button>
);
const ConnectedDispatchObject = connect(mapStateToProps, {
  deleteItem,
})(ItemMapDispatchObject);
//if mapDispatchToProps is a function then that function needs
//  to return an object where each property of that object is a
//  function that will dispatch an action. These properties
//  will be added to component props by react-redux
const ItemMapDispatchFunction = ({ item, deleteItem }) => (
  // no dispatch needed and no id needs to be passed
  <button onClick={deleteItem}>
    function - delete {item.name}
  </button>
);
const ConnectedItem3 = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  (dispatch, { id }) => ({
    deleteItem: () => dispatch(deleteItem(id)),
  })
)(ItemMapDispatchFunction);
//using hooks (not using connect at all)
const Hooks = ({ id }) => {
  //should use reselect but for simplicity not used
  const item = useSelector((state) =>
    state.items.find((item) => item.id === id)
  );
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  return (
    <button onClick={() => dispatch(deleteItem(item.id))}>
      hooks - delete {item.name}
    </button>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <ConnectedDispatchUndefined id={1} />
      <ConnectedDispatchObject id={1} />
      <ConnectedItem3 id={1} />
      <Hooks id={1} />
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/4.0.5/redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/7.2.0/react-redux.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and effort. The code you wrote is turning my brain into scrambled eggs. But I will understand it sooner or later.